# python *args **kwargs used in a que

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, keyword-argument

So i have been using the *args **kwargs functionality in python for a while and I came across a problem that I can't seem to find a solution to in the documentation/here on stackoverflow.

I have a multithreaded job which sends requests to the server in parallel, and then does some analysis on the JSON that is returned. I need to write to a csv file a line for each request-response pair.

because this is done in parallel, it will be problematic to write to the csv in the threaded job function. The solution I came up with is to put the analysis result in a que as well and then make a function to grab it from the analysis from the que and write it to the csv in order.

Now to the the real problem:
the function that I have to write to the csv takes arguments and keyword arguments, but the que doesn't know how to handle that.

Is there a way to put *args **kwargs in a que then getting them one by one and passing them to another function?

I want something that would look like this:

```
csv_que = Queue() 

# put arguments to the que which will be written later  
def write_row_to_que(self,*args, **kwargs):
    csv_que.put(*args, **kwargs)

# send each argument in the que to the write_row function with the arguments 
#from the que
def csv_writer_func():
    while True:
        args, kwargs = csv_que.get()
        write_row(args, kwargs)
```

I dont know if this is the right way to go about solving this but I would love to hear some thought and if this functionality (to pass arguments to a que and then pull them from it) is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mod should be enough to get you started:

```
def write_row_to_que(self,*args, **kwargs):
    csv_que.put( (args, kwargs) )
```

Put the parameters into a tuple and the `get()` method at the other end will retrieve them.

```
args, kwargs = csv_que.get()
```

This line will retrieve the items, but:

1. `args` will be a tuple of the unnamed arguments.
2. `kwargs` will be a dictionary of the keyword arguments originally supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the actual objects as a tuple, without unpacking them:

```
csv_que = Queue() 

# put arguments to the que which will be written later  
def write_row_to_que(self,*args, **kwargs):
    csv_que.put((args, kwargs))

# send each argument in the que to the write_row function with the arguments 
#from the que
def csv_writer_func():
    while True:
        args, kwargs = csv_que.get()
        write_row(args, kwargs)
```

Comment: You probably want `write_row(*args, **kwargs)`, though.